# 'The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error'. WCF Service, when deployed on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, deployment

I'm trying to consume a service, that I created,  the service consumes perfectly when its deployed on the localhost. But when I try to consume the same service after deploying it on the server(IIS). I get the following error

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Details about my service: I call upon a 3rd party service :
http://www.webservicex.net/sunsetriseservice.asmx?op=GetSunSetRiseTime
to create my service.

EDIT:
Full Stack Trace:

```
Stack Trace: 


[FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +10614671
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +336
   ServiceReference1.IService.sunsetSunRiseTime(String strlatitude, String strlongitude) +0
   _Default.btSubmit_click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +85
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9553178
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

**EDIT 2:** Service Description :
http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=65&CATID=12
Is this because I'm using an **asmx** service instead of **.svc** . Sorry if I sound confused! 
**EDIT 3** Server side web.config : https://gist.github.com/KodeSeeker/5226269

**EDIT 4:** ** With IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults set true( P.S. Im working on a remote server that keeps disconnecting so Im not sure if this error is also because of that ):

```
Stack Trace: 


[FaultException`1: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +10614671
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +336
   ServiceReference1.IService.sunsetSunRiseTime(String strlatitude, String strlongitude) +0
   _Default.btSubmit_click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +85
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9553178
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception

Comment: A basic principle of webservices is that as long as you get the soap messages right, it doesn't matter what the technologies on each end are. Both the old ASMX and the WCF clients are able to capable of getting the soap right, so it's not that. Your error message is extremely vague. It's not impossible that your third party is having technical difficulties, but most like you're just calling it wrong. Do they have samples for how to call them? If so, have you tried the samples?

Comment: @RuiJarimba: Added the stack trace!

Comment: Added details of the service in the question . Please have a look

Comment: no you need to turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults as its instructing you to, then post the error

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 :Done. Have a look now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002438/the-http-request-was-forbidden-with-client-authentication-scheme-anonymous

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at this message:

> The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'

Do you have Anonymous authentication enabled in IIS? You can check that in IIS Manager.

[image]

Comment: post your web.config for your service